# How do I select a row, then transpose it, and then stack it with the rest in R?

Tags: r, data.table

Lets say I have this dataset,

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- data.table(col1=c(11,21,31),
                             col2=c(12,22,32),
                             col3=c(13,23,33))

mydata 

       col1 col2 col3
    1:   11   12   13
    2:   21   22   23
    3:   31   32   33
```

What I need is:

- Select the first row and transpose it.
- Then, select the second row **and** stack it under the first row.
- Then, select the third row **and** stack it under the second...etc.

I have 1,135 rows. The dumb solution is to do this manually. For example,

```
mynewdata=t(data.frame(mydata[1,],mydata[2,],mydata[3,]))

mynewdata

            [,1]
    col1     11
    col2     12
    col3     13
    col1.1   21
    col2.1   22
    col3.1   23
    col1.2   31
    col2.2   32
    col3.2   33
```

until, I get to the 1,135th row. I know it must involve some kind of looping? But I don't know how to loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Essentially this is a melt by row. This seems inefficient but maybe `melt(mydata[,row := .I], id.vars="row")[order(row)]` ?

Comment: you can include `data.table` when asking about it

Comment: For what it's worth, there is a `transpose` function that can create that column: `unlist(transpose(as.list(mydata)))`.

Comment: @Frank - that is answer-worthy - not a function I've ever seen before - the `as.list` is also not necessary - `unlist(transpose(mydata))`

Comment: @thelatemail Okay. I imagine that transposing a data.table is more costly than a vanilla list, and I think `as.list` won't make copies of vectors, so I think I'll show it both ways.

Comment: @thelatemail I wish `transpose` was better advertised, it's awesome! I think it was designed as simply a helper for `tstrsplit` but it's incredibly useful myriad situations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially a `melt` operation with a row id. Try:

```
out <- setkey(melt(mydata[,row := .I], id.vars="row"),row)
out

#   row variable value
#1:   1     col1    11
#2:   1     col2    12
#3:   1     col3    13
#4:   2     col1    21
#5:   2     col2    22
#6:   2     col3    23
#7:   3     col1    31
#8:   3     col2    32
#9:   3     col3    33
```

In base R speak, this is a `stack`:

```
out <- cbind(row=seq_len(nrow(mydata)),stack(mydata))
out[order(out$row),]

#  row values  ind
#1   1     11 col1
#4   1     12 col2
#7   1     13 col3
#2   2     21 col1
#5   2     22 col2
#8   2     23 col3
#3   3     31 col1
#6   3     32 col2
#9   3     33 col3
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I need is:
>
> - Select the first row and transpose it.
> - Then, select the second row **and** stack it under the first row.
> - Then, select the third row **and** stack it under the second...etc.

For that task, the `transpose` function from the data.table package can help:

```
unlist(transpose(mydata))
# V11 V12 V13 V21 V22 V23 V31 V32 V33 
#  11  12  13  21  22  23  31  32  33
```

or maybe `unlist(transpose(as.list(mydata)))`.

---

I think you probably want to keep track of the rows and cols that the values in this vector came from, in which case you'll want to follow @thelatemail's answer or manually construct everything:

```
data.table(
  values = unlist(transpose(mydata)),
  col    = seq_along(mydata),
  row    = rep(seq(nrow(mydata)), each = length(mydata))
)

#    values col row
# 1:     11   1   1
# 2:     12   2   1
# 3:     13   3   1
# 4:     21   1   2
# 5:     22   2   2
# 6:     23   3   2
# 7:     31   1   3
# 8:     32   2   3
# 9:     33   3   3
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Why has no one suggested `c(t(mydata))`? Is `transpose` going to be faster? (On my phone, so can't test.)

Comment: Nevermind. Online now. Had a chance to add an answer :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto D'oh. Good point. I just posted this at tlm's recommendation (comments above), but vanilla `t` makes sense here.

Comment: I know. Thela can push people to do strange things ;-)

Comment: Good answer, plus one.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach in R to "unlist by row", which is what you seem to be doing, is to use the `c(t(yourdata))` approach:

```
c(t(mydata))
# [1] 11 12 13 21 22 23 31 32 33
```

If you want that as a single column matrix, like you show in your answer, do:

```
matrix(c(t(mydata)))
#       [,1]
# [1,]   11
# [2,]   12
# [3,]   13
# [4,]   21
# [5,]   22
# [6,]   23
# [7,]   31
# [8,]   32
# [9,]   33
```

Or, if you want information about the row and column from which the data came, you have a slightly more tricky:

```
do.call(CJ, lapply(dim(mydata), sequence))[, values := c(t(mydata))][]
#    V1 V2 values
# 1:  1  1     11
# 2:  1  2     12
# 3:  1  3     13
# 4:  2  1     21
# 5:  2  2     22
# 6:  2  3     23
# 7:  3  1     31
# 8:  3  2     32
# 9:  3  3     33
```

#### Benchmarks

This fairly manual approach can be speedy.

***Sample data***

```
set.seed(1)
nrow <- 100000
ncol <- 150
DT <- data.table(matrix(sample(100, nrow*ncol, TRUE), nrow = nrow))
```

***Functions***

Note: I've added a couple of optimizations to `funFrank` to cut it down from ~ 15 seconds to about 1 second with the sample data above. Optimizations include using `use.names = FALSE` in `unlist` and using `seq_len` instead of `seq`.

```
funAM <- function(indt) {
  setnames(do.call(CJ, lapply(dim(indt), seq_len)), 
           c("row", "col"))[, value := c(t(indt))][]
}

funThela <- function(indt) {
  setkey(melt(indt[,row := .I], id.vars="row"),row)[]
}

funFrank <- function(indt) {
  data.table(
    values = unlist(transpose(indt), use.names = FALSE),
    col    = seq_along(indt),
    row    = rep(seq_len(nrow(indt)), each = length(indt))
  )
}
```

***Results***

Note: I've used `copy(DT)` for Thela's approach since they've used `:=` on the original dataset to create the "row" column.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funAM(DT), funThela(copy(DT)), funFrank(DT))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#           funAM(DT) 163.7426  361.9589  388.9481  388.1012  425.0953  567.3669   100
#  funThela(copy(DT)) 583.5059  820.9864  881.4213  881.0558  949.5294 1109.9505   100
#        funFrank(DT) 866.5126 1109.7642 1201.5819 1176.9385 1292.6878 1633.0974   100
```

Comment: Nicely done. Not the first time you've one-upped me. :-)

Comment: @thelatemail, well, reshaping data is kinda one of my things.... Though I think it's one of yours too....